# How to stretch an array to a new length while keeping same value distribution?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a numpy array of length n that looks like this
 `[2.456970453262329, 2.3738574981689453,... 1.28790283203125,]`

and I want to "stretch" is so that it now has length m (m>n) but still keeps the same general distribution of values, how could I do that? Is there a numpy module for such a transformation?

e.g. for n=3 and m=5
`[1, 2, 3] --> [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]`

Comment: sounds like you want to interpolate. scipy has a submodule for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just looking for linear interpolation. [`np.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) will do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np


# wrapper function for convenience
def interp1d(array: np.ndarray, new_len: int) -> np.ndarray:
    la = len(array)
    return np.interp(np.linspace(0, la - 1, num=new_len), np.arange(la), array)


print(interp1d(np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), new_len=5)) # [1.  1.5 2.  2.5 3. ]
print(interp1d(np.asarray([0, 2, 3]), new_len=6)) # [0.  0.8 1.6 2.2 2.6 3. ]
# can even shorten arrays as well
print(interp1d(np.asarray([0, -2, 1, 3]), new_len=3)) # [ 0.  -0.5  3. ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the spacing between each element in the array is always equal regardless of how much "stretching" you apply, it sounds like `arange` will work for your use case since you can just specify a step https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange

Comment: this works for a uniform distribution and equal spacing, but I think the OP's looking for something more general